# SAS: Filling the variables with data from 2 datasets more a list loop

Tags: loops, date, sas

I'm new on SAS and I'd like to do this:

I have this three datasets:

```
Dataset01 (DS1):
Id     |Begin_date    |End_date
d      |01jun2022     |10jun2022  
b      |02jun2022     |06jun2022
c      |02jun2022     |07jun2022
```

```
Dataset02 (ds2):
Date        |
05/06/2021  |
06/06/2021  |
```

```
Dataset03 (ds3):
id   |max_days |
a    |3        |
b    |3        |
c    |2        |
d    |2        |
e    |4        |
f    |5        |
g    |2        |
h    |3        |
i    |4        |
j    |2        |
k    |4        |
l    |4        |
m    |3        |
n    |3        |
o    |5        |
p    |4        |
q    |3        |
r    |3        |
```

Output condition.a1: every day of the year is one row.

Output condition.a2: each day must have 7 ids on the row.

What i'd like to do is this:

**a.**Fill the variables with the ids from Dataset01, daily;

**b.**If the number of ids for one day is not enough, fill with ids from Dataset02

Condition.b1. can't repeat the same id on a day

Condition.b2. max number of times the id can fill the blanks before pass to next id: Dataset03.max_days

Condition.b3. days listed on Dataset02 do not count for the condition.b2 (above)

**c.**When the list of ids (Dataset03) is over, start again from the beggining.

OUTPUT wanted:

```
Date      |var_01  |var_02  |var_03  |var_04  |var_05  |var_06  |var_07  |
01jun2022 | d(DS1) | a(ds3) | b(ds3) | c(ds3) | e(ds3) | f(ds3) | g(ds3) |
02jun2022 | d(DS1) | b(DS1) | c(DS1) | a(ds3) | e(ds3) | f(ds3) | g(ds3) |
03jun2022 | d(DS1) | b(DS1) | c(DS1) | a(ds3) | e(ds3) | f(ds3) | h(ds3) |
04jun2022 | d(DS1) | b(DS1) | c(DS1) | e(ds3) | f(ds3) | h(ds3) | i(ds3) |
05jun2022 | d(DS1) | b(DS1) | c(DS1) |        |        |        |        |
06jun2022 | d(DS1) | b(DS1) | c(DS1) |        |        |        |        | 
07jun2022 | d(DS1) | b(ds3) | c(DS1) | f(ds3) | h(ds3) | i(ds3) | j(ds3) |
08jun2022 | d(DS1) | b(ds3) | c(ds3) | i(ds3) | j(ds3) | k(ds3) | l(ds3) |
09jun2022 | d(DS1) | i(ds3) | k(ds3) | l(ds3) | m(ds3) | n(ds3) | o(ds3) |
10jun2022 | d(DS1) | k(ds3) | l(ds3) | m(ds3) | n(ds3) | o(ds3) | p(ds3) |
```

TKS!!

Comment: I don't understand why you are showing the result in that strange spreadsheet like structure.  Shouldn't you just have a dataset with two variables,  DATE and ID.  So there will be 7 observations for 01JUN2022 and only three for 05JUN2022?

Comment: Hello, tks for ur reply.

The business problem is: out of office schedule. I cant't have more than 7 employees off frim the office in one day.

Ids=employee id

Dataset01 is a vacation dataset, with the employee id, beginning and end period.

Dataset02 is the holiday and weekend list.

Dataset03 is the list of all employees with the number of home-office days (according their work contract). It's a looping list.

Tks.